# I want sender to be 'noreply@salesforce.com'

Tags: email

I received the email with sender name my email from salesforce account when case creation notification happend.

But I want the email should come from noreplay@salesforce.com

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask). You will need to [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/413586/edit) your question to include more details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able to validate an email address before you can use it. As such, it's not possible to use that address. If you have your own email server, you can set up an address for that, such as noreply@mycompany.com. This is what most organizations do.